# GCP Config Create Gateway Bug

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform-provider-gcp, google-cloud-api-gateway

It doesn't seem possible to create an API Gateway config for a gateway i've created using:

`gcloud api-gateway apis create test-api --project=acme-prd`

Then the following command fails

```bash
gcloud api-gateway api-configs create 01 \
  --api=test-api --openapi-spec=./acme-web-gateway-v2.yaml \
  --project=acme-prd --backend-auth-service-account=svc-owner@acme-prd.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

With the error:

> ERROR: (gcloud.api-gateway.api-configs.create) FAILED_PRECONDITION: API Gateway Management Service Agent does not have permission to create Service Configs for Service "test-api-3qz6mxqfw7klr.apigateway.acme-prd.cloud.goog", or the Service does not exist.

Noting the service account `svc-owner@acme-prd.iam.gserviceaccount.com` has Owner privileges on the project.

Is there something I am missing? This is preventing a Terraform deployment. I've used `gcloud` commands to demonstrate the issue.

Also of note, this does not work in the GCP UI either. :(

Permissions granted to the account being used:

[image]

Cheers
KH

Comment: It wasn't useful unfortunately. Thanks

Comment: can you post the output of thihs command`gcloud api-gateway apis describe API_ID --project=PROJECT_ID`

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this, you will need to ensure that the Service Agent account has the necessary permissions for the specified service. Check API Gateway Service Account and verify if it has “Service Account User '' role associated with it.The `apigateway.apis.create` should  have owner/editor permissions.

Check the Google Cloud Console or by using command  `gcloud services list` to see if the Gateway API, Service Management API, Service Control API are enabled because these api are prerequisites.You will need to enable it if it is not already enabled.you enable by using below commands:

```
gcloud services enable apigateway.googleapis.com
gcloud services enable servicemanagement.googleapis.com
gcloud services enable servicecontrol.googleapis.com
```

Attaching documents for  [creating an api](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/configure-dev-env#configuring_a_service_account), [Gateway API access](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/api-access-overview) , [Troubleshooting](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/troubleshoot) for your reference.

**Edit-1**:

I have tried to create an API Gateway config for a gateway using below steps and successfully created an api config

1. Create an api gateway using below command

   gcloud api-gateway apis create test-api
2. Creating an API config using the below command.

   gcloud api-gateway api-configs create 01    --api=test-api --openapi-spec=openapi2-functions.yaml --project=project-id

Output is

```
waiting for API Config [01] to be created for API [test-api]...done.
```

I have taken openapi2-functions. Yaml file for this doc. Can you check if your yaml files has any mistakes.

The image below has the api config that i have created.
[image]

I have followed this [guide](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/secure-traffic-gcloud), can try to create an api gateway using this and let me know if you have an issues.

Comment: The above is all satisfied. I am not sure what you mean by "The apigateway.apis.create should have owner/editor permissions." Could you elaborate please? I've added an image showing IAM privileges.

Comment: `Apigateway.apis.create` permission is needed to create an api gateway, as i can see you have apigatway Admin which will be enough for creating an api gateway, can you make sure that you have api’s enabled. Ensure that you are using the correct credentials and Service name when creating the Service Config, check if the Service exists.

Comment: The apis are enabled. The service name is correct. Everything above checks out but the configs fail to create. This process works in other projects. Does ApiGateway output any logs I can view to get a more detailed analysis?

Comment: @KnowHoper Can you check the edited answer and let me know if this resolves your issues.